Bibliography not showing up using biber 2.17
I had written my bibliography and it was fine until yesterday. Yesterdday, I added a source then compiled in texstudio (biber 2.17, biblatex 3.17, ubuntu 22.04, default bibliography program in options is biber) and these messages came up.
Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 228.
Use of uninitialized value $tool in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 307.
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'bibliography.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'bibliography.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

I read some posts where something with the cache was discussed but they were talking for older versions and I think it was fixed in later biber/biblatex versions.
I tried, probably unsuccessfully and maybe in the wrong directory because terminal returned
No cache - you are not running the PAR::Packer executable version of biber, to clean the cache. I deleted all other files except .tex and .bib and recompiled and still nothing is fixed. The commands where
cd /tmp/
rm -rf `biber --cache`

So what is the problem? How do I fix it? I didn't find any other post around this.
Let me know if a MWE is needed.
Edit: I created a minimal document in another directory and no error came up. So as suggested I post a MWE. I updated the post with the commands used in terminal when cleaning the cache.
Neither the minimal document with biblatex-examples.bib, nor my MWE give an error in a different directory. The original files are saved in a usb, while the test files are saved on the computer.

Make a minimal document which cites ONE source from biblatex-examples.bib. Compile in a clean directory. If you get an error, post the source and the log file. If you don't get an error, reduce your real case to a minimal example and post the code for that example and the error. You don't say how you tried to clean the cache so if you did do it wrong, nobody is in a position to help you correct the mistake.

I've added tag [tag:ubuntu], because it seems you are using the Ubuntu version of biber not the upstream TeX Live package. Therefore it does not use a cache and the cache cannot be cleared. Have you done a linux update since yesterday? Can you show a minimal working example with bibliography?

This was resolve in biber 2.18. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/403.

BTW: The missing bibliography.bcf (if it is really missing) is a indication, that you either haven't done a LaTeX run before or there was an error at the run. Or maybe biber cannot find it, because you are using a build directory. If so, deactivate the usage of a build directory. It is always a source of harm.

If it was a cache problem you'd get a different error. I'm not sure why @cabohah thinks this is Ubuntu? Certainly looks like Linux distro-packaged (though FreeBSD etc. probably uses a similar path.)

I updated my question as suggested in the first comment.

Reading that bug report, those warnings are harmless. The issue is definitely the previous compilation failing to produce a bcf. If your MWE doesn't reproduce the issue, we can't use it to help you debug the problem. Look in the log file from the compilation i.e. before you run biber. It should tell you something about why there is no bcf. Otherwise, make a copy and remove stuff until you find the cause or have minimal code we can use to reproduce the problem.

@cfr But why didn't it get fixed when i deleted all the files and recompiled?       @cabohah I updated yesterday with sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade The bibliography.bcf file was indeed missing in the directory. I will update with a MWEB

Are you saying that the exact same files compiled OK in one directory and not in the original directory? Or are you saying that a minimised example compiles OK but your real document doesn't? The latter just means the minimal example doesn't include the problem. The former would obviously be different.

The MWE didn't give an error. I just tried the original and it gives the same errors.

Just to avoid misunderstandings: An example that does not give the error does not help to find the error (see the link in my comment). If there is an error while the LaTeX run, please also add the error message from the log file as code to your question. If you've forgotten to do a LaTeX run before running biber, please try the whole build process: LaTeX + biber + LaTeX + LaTeX. LaTeX in this case can mean either PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX depending on your document.

I am suggesting that this discussion be moved to the chat. The files are changing mood every time I answer a comment. The problem got fixed when compiling once the .tex then .bib and then twice the .tex i.e. F5, F8 F5, F5.

You should never run any compilation command (LaTeX or BibTeX/Biber) on the .bib file. Those commands are all best run on the base name of the main .tex file. For your editor that most likely means that the main .tex file should be in focus (or that you have some kind of project setting that explicitly sets the main .tex file). (The error Cannot find 'bibliography.bcf'! makes me think Biber was run on the .bib file and not the .tex file - unless your main document .tex file is called bibliography.tex) ...

... If you start fresh, you need to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX in that order. If you later modify only parts of your document, it might be enough to run just LaTeX (if there were no changes to citations and the .bib file). You can always check the .log file, where rerun requests are mentioned. You also need to rerun Biber and then LaTeX if you change anything about the .bib file. From time to time you will want to run the full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX sequence just to make sure everything comes out alright. You can read more about that at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Thank you all for the info! I didn't know that I shouldn't hit F8 on the .bib file. I will stop it. @moewe I guess that this was the problem since it got fixed. So you can close the question as duplicate.
